# Using a method in JFrame Form (GUI - Java)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

So my questions is pretty basic. I have a code of 7-8 lines which does the exact same thing, gets the text of *4 Text Panes* and updates them to a *5th Text Pane*, now thing is whenever any change is made to one of those *4 Text Panes*, this *5th text pane* will be updated, so I have to use that same 7-8 lines of code on all the *ActionPerformed* methods of those *4 Text Panes*. Is there any way to make a method somewhere which has those 7-8 lines and just call it in all those *4 Text Panes*.

Comment: What are you using as a listener on the text panes? You're talking about an `actionPerformed` method which would be registered using `addActionListener`, but TextPanes do not support action listeners. So what listener are you registering or is TextPane defined by you and you're using some different swing component, e.g. a JLabel, if yes, which?

Comment: I am actually pretty new to this, so I just know that I didn't add any ActionListener, I am using NetBeans which has this Design menu. I added those *Text Panes* from there, clicked on those Text Panes and these ActionPerformed methods were added automatically. The code is pretty basic, it's a simple GUI which takes 4 fields and adds them to a 5th one but I want to ask if there is any way to make the code reusable.

Comment: *whenever any change is made to one of those 4 Text Panes,* - how is the change made? Do you update as every character is typed? Or do you type a complete sentence and click an "Update" button? * I have to use that same 7-8 lines of code on all the ActionPerformed methods of those 4 Text Panes.* - a JTextPane does not support an ActionListener. Post a proper [mre] demonstrating your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just read you're using the NetBeans graphical editor and it auto generated those methods for you.

The easiest solution would be to create a method yourself somewhere all the other methods can access and then just call that in all the `ActionPerformed()`s.

```
// use the same parameters as currently given to your ActionPerformed
public void ActionPerformed1(Event param) {
    onTextPaneUpdate(param);
}
public void ActionPerformed2(Event param) {
    onTextPaneUpdate(param);
}
public void ActionPerformed3(Event param) {
    onTextPaneUpdate(param);
}

// use the same parameters as currently given to your ActionPerformed
public void onTextPaneUpdate(Event param) {
    // your code for all methods
}
```

If the `ActionPerformed`s are in different classes / files, you can just create your own class e.g. `MyTextPaneUpdateListener` and declare this `onTextPaneUpdate` method static, this way you could call it from everywhere without having any object to call it on. (`MyTextPaneUpdateListener.onTextPaneUpdate(params...)`)

In case this doesn't help you please provide example code that you're currently using as the answer heavily depends on your current implementation.

Comment: Oh man I feel so stupid right now. I was actually just forgetting parameters so it was giving me error on next method and I thought that I can't make methods in JFrame. Thank you, this made me realize my mistake.